# Eliminate $t$ to give an equation that relates $x$ and $y$

Tags: calculus, parametric

I am having problems understanding how to solve the following parametric equation. I have achieved an answer, but am unsure if my answer is correct or not.

### Eliminate t to give an equation that relates x and y:

$x= \sec(t)$, $y=\tan^2(t)-2$

***must solve for:***

$y=$

### My solution

$t = \sec^{-1}(x)$

***Insert this value of $t$ in the equation for $y$.***

$y=\tan^2(\sec^{-1}(x))-2$

*Supplementary notes: for a point on the the curve:*

$f(t)= \sec(t)$

$g(t)=\tan^2(t)-2$

*where $z$ is some number*

$P_{point}(f(z),g(z))$

Please confirm or reject my answer.

Comment: It might easier to consider the identity $sec^2(t) = 1+ tan^2(t)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "supplementary notes" onwards I don't quite understand. An easier way is using that $\tan^2t + 1 = \sec^2t$, so that: $$y = \tan^2t-2 = 1+\tan^2t - 3 = \sec^2t - 3 = x^2-3.$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but i remain quite uncertain on the exact solution then. You show that the solution is $x^2 -3$, which is not equivalent to my solution, as my solution has the restriction on values between ${-1 <x <1}$. Are both equations possible solutions? I apologize for my confusion as this is a relatively new topic for me and am having problems completely understanding it (I have researched, although am still uncertain). May you please clarify.

Comment: if it is of any help I have created this graph on Desmos online calculator comparing our results. [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/brswyvcerw)

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention anything about domains, so neither did I. The identity $\tan^2t + 1 = \sec^2t$ is valid for all $t$ on which $\cos t \neq 0$. So if you fix a domain for $t$, we can find the correspondent range for $x$ (and hence for $y$)

Comment: So that means the domain restriction I imposed on the graph is correct? If so, then why is the solution $x^2-3$. I apologize again, I am currently having trouble wrapping my head around this (parametric equations).

Comment: When they say to "eliminate" $t$, you have to make all $t$ disappear. Look again at the computation in the answer, it is straightforward. We make the expression for $x$ appear in the expression for $y$, then substitute. And I don't know what domain you took for $t$ (you should have added it in the question)

Comment: That really does help clarify things! Thank you!,, and for the domain the equation (inside of my question) $y=tan(sec^{-1}(x))^2-1$ imposes the restriction that $-1<x<1$ (or at least it does to my knowledge).

Answer (score 4):

I will add another answer, because the method is so useful for any calculus problem involving trig substitutions or anything of the sort. (You will not need to remember any trig identities based on the Pythagorean Theorem.)

Starting off with $x = \sec t$, construct a right-triangle have the appropriate side lengths (here hypotenuse=$x$, adjacent=$1$) and determine the "other" side length using the Pythagorean Theorem.

Then simply read the values of other trig functions from the triangle by their definitions:

$\tan t = \dfrac{opposite}{adjacent} = \sqrt{x^2-1}$

so

$\tan^2 t = x^2-1$

[image]

Comment: If i could award multiple answers, I would. Thank you for helping clarify this question.

Answer (score 3):

The identity $\color{blue}{\sec^2t=\tan^2t+1}$ imply
$$y+2=\tan^2t=\sec^2 t-1=x^2-1$$

Answer (score 3):

$\cos^{2} t+\sin^{2} t =1$, so $1+\tan^{2}t = \sec^{2}t$ so $y+3=x^{2}$